# Writing MBR bootstrap code as a UEFI bootloader

Tags: unix, uefi, mbr, x86, decompile

I'm really interested in retrocomputing, and as I was looking for a so-called "pure" version of AT&T UNIX v7 I came across this port to the x86 architecture called v7/x86. It seemed interesting, so I took a crack at downloading it.

However, I ran into a problem. My machine is UEFI-based, and I don't have any other storage devices on me besides my hard drive and v7/x86 CD. Since this OS uses an MBR bootstrap, is it possible to decompile to assembly and write a UEFI bootloader using EDK II for it?

Comment: Have you already ruled out the possibility of running v7/x86 as a virtual machine through qemu or VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes that’s been ruled out; this is a scenario where I wouldn’t have access to a VM and have to run bare-metal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentative answer as I've not written any low-level code myself:

If your machine's firmware has a "CSM" or "Legacy boot" option, just use that. It provides full BIOS emulation, from MBR bootstrap to runtime services, and should be able to start v7/x86 as is.

If your machine has no such option at all (which would be rare), then a custom UEFI-based bootloader may be possible but would only work if the OS itself does not rely on *any* features that BIOS interrupts would provide, because there is no BIOS. (E.g. as far as I know, the plain 80x25 text mode does not exist in UEFI world, and the "disk access" `int 13h` functions definitely do not.)